# Why My Code Can Play Video In All Browsers Except Safari?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, iframe

I'm developing a site which needs to play videos in iFrame, it works mostly correct except Safari, if I click on a video in Safari, it won't play, but if I click on it a few times, it starts to play but without image, I can only hear the sound, why ? How to fix it ?

My minimum code looks like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.ahrefs.com/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link media="all" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,300,100italic,100,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic">
    <link media="screen" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.ahrefs.com/assets/css/home-responsive.css?20180815-001">

    <style>

      div.Table
      {
        font-size: 218%;
        text-align: center;
      }

      tr a{ font-size: 18px;color:#aabbcc; }
      tr a:hover { color:#ddeeff; }

      #modal
      {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        max-height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(24, 24, 24, .6);
        z-index: 999;
      }
      #modal .content
      {
        position: relative;
        width: 55%;
        height: 65vh;
        margin: auto; /* allows horyzontal and vertical alignment as .content is in flex container */
      }
      #modal .content .yt-video
      {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: calc(100% - 45px);
      }
      #modal .content .title
      {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 23px;
        padding: 12px 4px;
        margin: 0;
        background: #007bff;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 26px;
        max-width: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
      }
      #modal .close
      {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 45px;
        height: 45px;
        line-height: 36px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 0;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 38px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #366;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: background .2s;
      }
      #modal .content .close .a { font-size:38px;color: #ffffff; }
      #modal .close:hover, #modal .close:active { background: #ff0000; }
      #modal.is-visible { display: flex; }

    </style>
  </head>

  <body class="page__guest ahrefs page-home">
    <div id="localizejs">
      <div class="content">

        <a id="Videos"></a>
        <div class="tools">
          <div class="container center">

                  <div class="tools-icon">
                    <a href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IgBIaZgoAQc?autoplay=1" target=_blank data-target="modal" data-video-title="Keypad Pins Easily Stolen"><img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IgBIaZgoAQc/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEXCPYBEIoBSFryq4qpAwkIARUAAIhCGAE=&rs=AOn4CLDW3KcjXsTR5utmlvhFfibLe-bvRg" width=170 height=110 alt="Keypad Pins Easily Stolen"></a>
                    <p class="tools-icon__text">Keypad Pins Easily Stolen</p>
                  </div>

          </div>
        </div>

      <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script defer src="js/home.js"></script>

    </div>

    <!-- the modal div that will open when an anchor link is clicked to show the related video in an iframe. -->

    <div id="modal">
      <div class="content">
        <div class="close"><a onclick = "return close_iFrame();">&times;</a></div>
        <h4 class="title">.</h4>
        <iframe class="yt-video" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      var modal = document.getElementById('modal'),
          closeBtn = modal.querySelector('close'),
          ytVideo = modal.querySelector('.content .yt-video'),
          title = modal.querySelector('.content .title'),
          anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a[data-target="modal"]'),
          l = anchors.length;

      for (var i = 0; i < l; i++)
      {
        anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function (e)
        {
          e.preventDefault();
          title.textContent = this.dataset.videoTitle || 'No title';
          ytVideo.src = this.href;
          modal.classList.toggle('is-visible');
          modal.focus();
        });
      }

      modal.addEventListener("keydown", function (e)
      {
        if (e.keyCode == 27)
        {
          title.textContent = '';
          ytVideo.src = '';
          this.classList.toggle('is-visible');
        }
      });

      function close_iFrame()
      {
        var modal = document.getElementById('modal'),
            ytVideo = modal.querySelector('.content .yt-video');

        ytVideo.src = '';
        modal.classList.toggle('is-visible');
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have Safari Version 11.1.2 (13605.3.8), its working as in chrome, I don't see any issues

Comment: Which comes to the hard question? What version of Safari? The Windows one is dead since a few years and corresponds to an IE8 for what web apis are concerned.  Would you use IE8 to test if your site works on Edge? Nope. Moreover, it never came to the point to reflect any osX version. So throw this away.

Comment: Thanks @PavanKumarJorrigala, glad to hear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you checked if Safari is compatible with every bit of code in your function? Most issue with it is because it's not up to date with a lot of thing. Same thing goes for IE (Edge).

Comment: YES, great answer and suggestions by @Kaiido , my Windows version is 5.1.7 [ 2007 - 2012 ], it's out of date, and no wonder it doesn't work properly. Glad to hear it works OK, thanks.